# Expresso Store changed column name in database

Tags: expresso-store, database, updating

We've built a custom report-system for a client, fetching data from the "exp_store_orders"-table and displaying them to admins.

Yesterday I updated the site to EE 2.8.1 and Store 2.3.1. After ironing out some wrinkles everything seemed fine. Except the PHP-script generating the report. We got a PHP-error: `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell you what gives: the first column in the database-table had been renamed. Used to be "order_id", now it's called plain "id". Changed the query and everything worked again.

But I couldn't find any information on this from Exp-resso, isn't renaming stuff in the database a big deal?

I should also mention that this is one of the few times we've gone outside of native EE- and addon-functionality, and we seldom look closely at the database...

Comment: What version were you coming from?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Store 2.0 was pretty much a complete rewrite, and everything changed - database tables, column names, PHP classes - which is why it was a major version bump. For more information, check out http://semver.org/

Comment: Jeremy: we came from 1.6.0